# set up status bar text color of a UINavigationController that is presented modally from a modal

Tags: ios

I have a modal view controller whose navigation controller's bar style is `"UIStatusBarStyleBlack"`, so its status bar text color is white.

However, if I present a `UINavigationController` modally from here and I want it to be have a bar style of `"UIStatusBarStyleDefault"`, I can't control the status bar text color.

I've tried everything suggested on SO (subclass, extensions, etc), but none of the solutions take this scenario into account (modal on a modal).

EDIT: This seems to only be the issue whenever it is presented from a non-fullscreen modal. So, if the first modal was fullscreen, everything works. But if it was a form sheet or popover on iPad, then the modal presented from there won't update the status bar color.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are presenting your view controller instead of a navigation controller.

First you need to create a navigation controller with root view controller as your view controller and then present that navigation controller.

If this is not the case then kindly post some code which shows how exactly you are currently approaching the case.